# Neither you nor I is

Tags: verb-agreement, neither-nor

I was struck by PM Johnson's 'neither he nor I are' a few days ago,
which seemed to me obviously ungrammatic, and searched this site, where I found this:

[Controversy over verb choice in "neither you nor I {is/am/are} in control"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122969/controversy-over-verb-choice-in-neither-you-nor-i-is-am-are-in-control)

where the answer claims that 'neither you nor I is' is 'of course .. totally wrong,' and that it would have to be 'neither you nor I am,'
since the verb is closer to 'I' than to 'you.'

I am unconvinced.  What are some authoritative sources on this issue?
**And is there really no authority, grammatic or literary, in support of
'neither you nor I is'?**

My sense is that it must be 'neither you nor I is' and 'neither he nor I
is.'  It seems to me that, regardless of what the pronoun closest to the
verb is, the third person ''wins'' when there is conflict, even when the
contestants are the 2nd & 1st persons.

(As regards the number of the verb, it seems to me that it *must* be
singular, seeing as what is being denied is a statement about a singular
thing, namely that (at least) one of two is something.)

NOTE that my bold-faced question has been implied but neither focused
nor answered in the other post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/neither-michael-nor-albert-is-correct-or-neither-michael-nor-albert-are-corre

Comment: There is alternation between singular and plural verb agreement, though singular agreement is usual. Plural agreement is informal and condemned by the prescritivists. One reason is that "neither" can only function as determiner to singular nouns: "Neither objection was valid" is grammatical, but *"Neither objections were valid" is definitely not.

Comment: Have a look at the link in the [accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/122981/142322) to the question you referenced.

Comment: Do you say *am't I, isn't I* or *aren't I*? You say *aren't I,* of course, even though *I* isn't plural. Similarly for *neither he nor I are wrong*.

Comment: @PeterShor, I may think a bit much of myself, but I would never dream of
saying _aren't I._
There's nothing in the way of saying _am I not._
And I don't think the two phenomona have similar causes.

Comment: Well, if you don't feel comfortable saying *aren't I*, the way most native speakers do, of course you wouldn't be happy with *neither he nor I are*. But you're certainly in the minority about the first expression. [See this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/im-right-arent-i).

Comment: Related, in light of issues broached in comments - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140677/neither-them-nor-us-vs-neither-they-nor-we